# Listbox won't scroll down with ishittestvisible on true

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I have a page where a scrollviewer and stackpanel wrap a listbox that loads text and button. The problem is when IsHitTestVisible is false then the button doesn't work but if the IsHitTestVisible is true the listbox cannot scroll to the bottom.

```
<ScrollViewer Name="scrollview" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Margin="0,0,0,0" Foreground="Black">
                    <StackPanel>

                            <ListBox Margin="0,0,0,20" Name="lbComments" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>

                    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: it is load in a object from other page

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: if IsHitTestVisible is false I cannot click the button but I can scroll down to the bottom of the listbox. If IshitTestVisble is true than I can click the button but I cannot scroll to the last item of the listbox